# JSON string becomes different value when converting to float

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, string-parsing

I'm parsing some weather JSON from a local file.

```
 "temp_f":40.1,
 "temp_c":4.5,
```

The problem is that when I parse it into an c value

```
NSLog(@"%f", [weatherDict[@"temp_f"]floatValue]);

//Logs: 40.099998
```

If I log it as a string value it returns `40.1`.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [weatherDict objectForKey:@"temp_f"]);
//Logs: 40.1
```

The problem seems to be when calling `floatValue`

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking "why".

The complete answer is found in the most famous article "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

It is a must read unless you want to be forever guessing why strange things happen with your numbers.

BTW. Use double, not float, unless you can give me a good reason why float would be better for you.

Comment: Thanks. No way I'm reading that entire article though; its like a book :)

Comment: Also, I'm starting college in a  few months (comp sci). Is this something you think I'll need to read?

Comment: @MendyK - It's something you need to understand reasonably well if you intend to continue in computer science.  The presentation is pretty arcane, but you should at least skim it well, or find something equivalent to study.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with float accuracy, use NSDecimal instead:

```
[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:weatherDict[@"temp_f"]];
```